# Why are the green movement buttons getting misplaced after captures in the checkers game I wrote?

Tags: python, tkinter, checkers

I wrote code for a checkers game and the rules for the game are as follows:

1. You can move a checker one diagonal space forward
2. Jump your opponents checkers to remove them from the board (forced capture)
3. If you can recapture after capturing a checker you must do so in the same move (You can chose which one if multiple captures
   are available)
4. When checkers reach the end of the opponents side they can move backwards and are known as 'king checkers'
5. You can win if all of your opponents checkers are over or your opponent has no legal moves

When you run the program, a TKinter window for the game pops up as shown below:

[TKinter Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXxDD.png)

After a capture, when a checker is moved, it's position doesn't update which leads  to the misplacement of the green buttons used to move the checkers.

Below is a video which consistently recreates the bug:

[Video to recreate the bug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F2hTbGUd0hU)

Below is a drive link with a series of images which also consistently recreates the bug:

[Images to recreate the bug](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1M2pIQcD-mBcIu-pUWxuXgZXacLpyi5TF?usp=sharing)

You may notice that in the second last image, the green movement button is placed incorrectly. Here there are 2 problems. The button should be diagonally placed but it is horizontally placed. There should be 2 buttons but there is 1. My hypothesis is that this is the result of the position of the Red Checkers not being updated. If the checker was in its original position, it is understandable that the green button that apeared was in the correct place and the other green button didn't have space to spawn.

**THIS IS A SILENT BUG AND THERE ARE NO ERROR MESSAGES**

I will now proceed to explain the code so that the person trying to help me has background information on how the code works.

The below code makes a non resizable tkinter window and draws the board:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Checkers")
root.resizable(False, False)

canvas_width, canvas_height = 400, 400

canvas = Canvas(root, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
canvas.pack()

x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1 = 0, 0, 50, 50

for i in range(4):
    for x in range(4):
        canvas.create_rectangle(x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1, fill="brown")
        x_0 += 100
        x_1 += 100
    x_0, x_1 = 50, 100
    y_0 += 50
    y_1 += 50
    for y in range(4):
        canvas.create_rectangle(x_0, y_0, x_1, y_1, fill="brown")
        x_0 += 100
        x_1 += 100
    x_0, x_1 = 0, 50
    y_0 += 50
    y_1 += 50
```

After this I create 2 dictionaries with the values of the coordinates of each checker stored as a list corresponding to it's number. Along with this I also assign variables for the images of the checkers and the green movement buttons (The images are available in the zip file at the end of this question).

```
red_checkers = {1: [75, 25], 2: [175, 25],
                3: [275, 25], 4: [375, 25],
                5: [25, 75], 6: [125, 75],
                7: [225, 75], 8: [325, 75],
                9: [75, 125], 10: [175, 125],
                11: [275, 125], 12: [375, 125]}

red_checker_image = PhotoImage(file="Red Checker.png").subsample(15, 15)
black_checker_image = PhotoImage(file="Black Checker.png").subsample(15, 15)
green_circle = PhotoImage(file="Green Circle.png"). subsample(20, 20)

black_checkers = {1: [25, 275], 2: [125, 275],
                  3: [225, 275], 4: [325, 275],
                  5: [75, 325], 6: [175, 325],
                  7: [275, 325], 8: [375, 325],
                  9: [25, 375], 10: [125, 375],
                  11: [225, 375], 12: [325, 375]}
```

I then assign a variable to each checker button. The buttons are initially created with the 'basic movement' function set as their command.

```
RedChecker1 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 1, red_checkers[1][0], red_checkers[1][1]))
RedChecker2 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 2, red_checkers[2][0], red_checkers[2][1]))
RedChecker3 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 3, red_checkers[3][0], red_checkers[3][1]))
RedChecker4 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 4, red_checkers[4][0], red_checkers[4][1]))
RedChecker5 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 5, red_checkers[5][0], red_checkers[5][1]))
RedChecker6 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 6, red_checkers[6][0], red_checkers[6][1]))
RedChecker7 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 7, red_checkers[7][0], red_checkers[7][1]))
RedChecker8 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 8, red_checkers[8][0], red_checkers[8][1]))
RedChecker9 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                     command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 9, red_checkers[9][0], red_checkers[9][1]))
RedChecker10 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                      command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 10, red_checkers[10][0], red_checkers[10][1]))
RedChecker11 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                      command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 11, red_checkers[11][0], red_checkers[11][1]))
RedChecker12 = Button(root, image=red_checker_image, border="0",
                      command=lambda: basic_movement("red", 12, red_checkers[12][0], red_checkers[12][1]))

BlackChecker1 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 1, black_checkers[1][0], black_checkers[1][1]))
BlackChecker2 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 2, black_checkers[2][0], black_checkers[2][1]))
BlackChecker3 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 3, black_checkers[3][0], black_checkers[3][1]))
BlackChecker4 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 4, black_checkers[4][0], black_checkers[4][1]))
BlackChecker5 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 5, black_checkers[5][0], black_checkers[5][1]))
BlackChecker6 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 6, black_checkers[6][0], black_checkers[6][1]))
BlackChecker7 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 7, black_checkers[7][0], black_checkers[7][1]))
BlackChecker8 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 8, black_checkers[8][0], black_checkers[8][1]))
BlackChecker9 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                       command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 9, black_checkers[9][0], black_checkers[9][1]))
BlackChecker10 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                        command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 10, black_checkers[10][0], black_checkers[10][1]))
BlackChecker11 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                        command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 11, black_checkers[11][0], black_checkers[11][1]))
BlackChecker12 = Button(root, image=black_checker_image, border="0",
                        command=lambda: basic_movement("black", 12, black_checkers[12][0], black_checkers[12][1]))
```

Next I create a dictionary of the buttons with an integer representing the key and the buttoon representing the value. I also make a list of the integers that represent the keys:

```
dict_of_black_checkers = {1: BlackChecker1, 2: BlackChecker2, 3: BlackChecker3, 4: BlackChecker4,
                          5: BlackChecker5, 6: BlackChecker6, 7: BlackChecker7, 8: BlackChecker8,
                          9: BlackChecker9, 10: BlackChecker10, 11: BlackChecker11, 12: BlackChecker12}

dict_of_red_checkers = {1: RedChecker1, 2: RedChecker2, 3: RedChecker3, 4: RedChecker4,
                        5: RedChecker5, 6: RedChecker6, 7: RedChecker7, 8: RedChecker8,
                        9: RedChecker9, 10: RedChecker10, 11: RedChecker11, 12: RedChecker12}

list_of_keys_black = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
list_of_keys_red = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

I then create a function to check the board for any available captures. this function work by checking to see if 2 spaces diagonal to a checker is empty and if 1 space diagonal to the checker is an enemy checker:

```
def check_captures(color):
    captures_list = []

    if color == 'red':
        for j in list_of_keys_red:
            if red_checkers[j + 1][0] not in [325, 375] and red_checkers[j + 1][1] not in [325, 375]:
                if [red_checkers[j + 1][0] + 50, red_checkers[j + 1][1] + 50] in black_checkers.values():
                    if [red_checkers[j + 1][0] + 100, red_checkers[j + 1][1] + 100] not in red_checkers.values() and \
                       [red_checkers[j + 1][0] + 100, red_checkers[j + 1][1] + 100] not in black_checkers.values():

                        captures_list.append(j)

        for k in list_of_keys_red:
            if red_checkers[k + 1][0] not in [25, 75] and red_checkers[k + 1][1] not in [325, 375]:
                if [red_checkers[k + 1][0] - 50, red_checkers[k + 1][1] + 50] in black_checkers.values():
                    if [red_checkers[k + 1][0] - 100, red_checkers[k + 1][1] + 100] not in red_checkers.values() and \
                       [red_checkers[k + 1][0] - 100, red_checkers[k + 1][1] + 100] not in black_checkers.values():

                        captures_list.append(k)

    elif color == 'black':
        for j in list_of_keys_black:
            if black_checkers[j + 1][0] not in [25, 75] and black_checkers[j + 1][1] not in [25, 75]:
                if [black_checkers[j + 1][0] - 50, black_checkers[j + 1][1] - 50] in red_checkers.values():
                    if [black_checkers[j + 1][0] - 100, black_checkers[j + 1][1] - 100] not in red_checkers.values() \
                            and [black_checkers[j + 1][0] - 100, black_checkers[j + 1][1] - 100] \
                            not in black_checkers.values():

                        captures_list.append(j)

        for k in list_of_keys_black:
            if black_checkers[k + 1][0] not in [325, 375] and black_checkers[k + 1][1] not in [25, 75]:
                if [black_checkers[k + 1][0] + 50, black_checkers[k + 1][1] - 50] in red_checkers.values():
                    if [black_checkers[k + 1][0] + 100, black_checkers[k + 1][1] - 100] not in red_checkers.values() \
                            and [black_checkers[k + 1][0] + 100, black_checkers[k + 1][1] - 100] \
                            not in black_checkers.values():

                        captures_list.append(k)

    return captures_list
```

I then create 6 functions to enable, disable and place the checkers on the board for both the colors.

```
def disabled_black():
    for j in dict_of_black_checkers:
        dict_of_black_checkers[j].configure(state="disabled")


def normal_black():
    for j in dict_of_black_checkers:
        dict_of_black_checkers[j].configure(state="normal")


def place_black():
    for j in dict_of_black_checkers:
        dict_of_black_checkers[j].place(x=black_checkers[j][0], y=black_checkers[j][1], anchor=CENTER)


def normal_red():
    for j in dict_of_red_checkers:
        dict_of_red_checkers[j].configure(state="normal")


def disabled_red():
    for j in dict_of_red_checkers:
        dict_of_red_checkers[j].configure(state="disabled")


def place_red():
    for j in dict_of_red_checkers:
        dict_of_red_checkers[j].place(x=red_checkers[j][0], y=red_checkers[j][1], anchor=CENTER)
```

I also call the place functions and the 'disabled_red' function since black starts first:

```
place_red()
place_black()
disabled_red()
```

now I define the 'basic_movement' function that was previusly used for the checker buttons. This function checks to see if one space diagonal to the checker is empty. If it is then it places a green movement button there.

```
def basic_movement(color, specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y):
    movement_button_1.place(x=1000, y=1000)
    movement_button_2.place(x=1000, y=1000)
    if color == "red":
        if checker_x + 50 < 376 and checker_y + 50 < 376 and [checker_x + 50, checker_y + 50] not in red_checkers.\
                values() and [checker_x + 50, checker_y + 50] not in black_checkers.values() and checker_x != 375:
            movement_button_2.place(x=checker_x + 50, y=checker_y + 50, anchor=CENTER)
            movement_button_2.configure(command=lambda: movement_2(
                specific_checker, color, [checker_x + 50, checker_y + 50]))
        if checker_x - 50 > 0 and checker_y + 50 < 376 and [checker_x - 50, checker_y + 50] not in red_checkers.\
                values() and [checker_x - 50, checker_y + 50] not in black_checkers.values() and checker_x != 25:
            movement_button_1.place(x=checker_x - 50, y=checker_y + 50, anchor=CENTER)
            movement_button_1.configure(command=lambda: movement_1(
                specific_checker, color, [checker_x - 50, checker_y + 50]))

    if color == "black":
        if checker_x + 50 < 376 and checker_y - 50 > 0 and [checker_x + 50, checker_y - 50] not in red_checkers.\
                values() and [checker_x + 50, checker_y - 50] not in black_checkers.values() and checker_x != 375:
            movement_button_2.place(x=checker_x + 50, y=checker_y - 50, anchor=CENTER)
            movement_button_2.configure(command=lambda: movement_2(
                specific_checker, color, [checker_x + 50, checker_y - 50]))
        if checker_x - 50 > 0 and checker_y - 50 > 0 and [checker_x - 50, checker_y - 50] not in red_checkers.\
                values() and [checker_x - 50, checker_y - 50] not in black_checkers.values() and checker_x != 25:
            movement_button_1.place(x=checker_x - 50, y=checker_y - 50, anchor=CENTER)
            movement_button_1.configure(command=lambda: movement_1(
                specific_checker, color, [checker_x - 50, checker_y - 50]))
```

I now define 2 functions, movement_1 and movement_2. These functions simply move the checkers when the green movement buttons are clicked.

```
def movement_1(specific, color, location):
    if color == "red":
        disabled_red()
        normal_black()

        red_checkers.update({specific: location})
        place_red()

        if len(check_captures('black')) != 0:
            disabled_black()
            for j in check_captures('black'):
                dict_of_black_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=black_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('black', specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

        movement_button_1.place(x=1000, y=1000)
        movement_button_2.place(x=1000, y=1000)

    if color == "black":
        disabled_black()
        normal_red()

        black_checkers.update({specific: location})

        if len(check_captures('red')) != 0:
            disabled_red()
            for j in check_captures('red'):
                dict_of_red_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=red_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('red', specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

        place_black()

        movement_button_1.place(x=1000, y=1000)
        movement_button_2.place(x=1000, y=1000)


def movement_2(specific, color, location):
    if color == "red":
        disabled_red()
        normal_black()

        red_checkers.update({specific: location})
        place_red()

        if len(check_captures('black')) != 0:
            disabled_black()
            for j in check_captures('black'):
                dict_of_black_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=black_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('black', specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

        movement_button_1.place(x=1000, y=1000)
        movement_button_2.place(x=1000, y=1000)

    if color == "black":
        disabled_black()
        normal_red()

        black_checkers.update({specific: location})
        place_black()

        if len(check_captures('red')) != 0:
            disabled_red()
            for j in check_captures('red'):
                dict_of_red_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=red_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('red', specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

        movement_button_1.place(x=1000, y=1000)
        movement_button_2.place(x=1000, y=1000)
```

I then define 2 functions for the captures. These functions move the checker to their final position upon a capture and delete the checker that it captured. Along with updating the relevant dictionaries after the capture.

```
def capture_movement_2(key, specific, color, final_x, final_y):
    global red_checkers
    global black_checkers

    if color == 'red':
        red_checkers.update({specific: [final_x, final_y]})

        del black_checkers[key]
        list_of_keys_black.remove(key - 1)

        dict_of_black_checkers[key].place(x=1000, y=1000)

        del dict_of_black_checkers[key]
        del checker_type_black[key]

        place_red()

        normal_red()
        if specific - 1 in check_captures('red'):
            dict_of_red_checkers[specific].configure(command=lambda: capture(
                'red', specific, red_checkers[specific][0], red_checkers[specific][1]))
            for j in dict_of_red_checkers:
                if j == specific:
                    continue
                dict_of_red_checkers[j].configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            disabled_red()
            normal_black()

            for k in list_of_keys_red:
                dict_of_red_checkers[k + 1].configure(command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[
                    k + 1][0], checker_y=red_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                    "red", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

            for k in list_of_keys_black:
                dict_of_black_checkers[k + 1].configure(
                    command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[
                        k + 1][0], checker_y=black_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                        "black", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

            for j in check_captures('black'):
                if check_captures('black')[0] == j:
                    disabled_black()
                dict_of_black_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=black_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('black', specific_checker, checker_x,
                                                                     checker_y))

    elif color == 'black':
        black_checkers.update({specific: [final_x, final_y]})

        del red_checkers[key]
        list_of_keys_red.remove(key - 1)

        dict_of_red_checkers[key].place(x=1000, y=1000)

        del dict_of_red_checkers[key]
        del checker_type_red[key]

        place_black()

        normal_black()
        if specific - 1 in check_captures('black'):
            dict_of_black_checkers[specific].configure(command=lambda: capture(
                'black', specific, black_checkers[specific][0], black_checkers[specific][1]))
            for j in dict_of_black_checkers:
                if j == specific:
                    continue
                dict_of_black_checkers[j].configure(state='disabled')
        else:
            disabled_black()
            normal_red()

            for k in list_of_keys_red:
                dict_of_red_checkers[k + 1].configure(command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[
                    k + 1][0], checker_y=red_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                    "red", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

            for k in list_of_keys_black:
                dict_of_black_checkers[k + 1].configure(
                    command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[
                        k + 1][0], checker_y=black_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                        "black", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

            for j in check_captures('red'):
                if check_captures('red')[0] == j:
                    disabled_red()
                dict_of_red_checkers[j + 1].configure(
                    state='normal', command=lambda specific_checker=j + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[j + 1]
                    [0], checker_y=red_checkers[j + 1][1]: capture('red', specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

    movement_button_1_capture.place(x=1000, y=1000)
    movement_button_2_capture.place(x=1000, y=1000)
```

The capture function that I define next just changes the command for the relevant checkers so that they place the movement buttons relevant to the capture rather than the basic movement.

```
def capture(color, specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y):
    movement_button_1_capture.place(x=1000, y=1000)
    movement_button_2_capture.place(x=1000, y=1000)
    if color == 'red':
        for k, v in black_checkers.items():
            if checker_x not in [325, 375] and checker_y not in [325, 375]:
                if [checker_x + 50, checker_y + 50] == v:
                    if [checker_x + 100, checker_y + 100] not in black_checkers.values():
                        if [checker_x + 100, checker_y + 100] not in red_checkers.values():
                            movement_button_2_capture.place(x=checker_x + 100, y=checker_y + 100, anchor=CENTER)
                            movement_button_2_capture.configure(command=lambda: capture_movement_2(
                                k, specific_checker, 'red', checker_x + 100, checker_y + 100))
                            break
        for key, value in black_checkers.items():
            if checker_x not in [25, 75] and checker_y not in [325, 375]:
                if [checker_x - 50, checker_y + 50] == value:
                    if [checker_x - 100, checker_y + 100] not in black_checkers.values():
                        if [checker_x - 100, checker_y + 100] not in red_checkers.values():
                            movement_button_1_capture.place(x=checker_x - 100, y=checker_y + 100, anchor=CENTER)
                            movement_button_1_capture.configure(command=lambda: capture_movement_1(
                                key, specific_checker, 'red', checker_x - 100, checker_y + 100))
                            break

    if color == 'black':
        for key1, val in red_checkers.items():
            if checker_x not in [325, 375] and checker_y not in [25, 75]:
                if [checker_x + 50, checker_y - 50] == val:
                    if [checker_x + 100, checker_y - 100] not in black_checkers.values() \
                            and [checker_x + 100, checker_y - 100] not in red_checkers.values():
                        movement_button_2_capture.place(x=checker_x + 100, y=checker_y - 100, anchor=CENTER)
                        movement_button_2_capture.configure(command=lambda: capture_movement_2(
                            key1, specific_checker, 'black', checker_x + 100, checker_y - 100))
                        break
        for key2, value2 in red_checkers.items():
            if checker_x not in [25, 75] and checker_y not in [25, 75]:
                if [checker_x - 50, checker_y - 50] == value2:
                    if [checker_x - 100, checker_y - 100] not in black_checkers.values() \
                            and [checker_x - 100, checker_y - 100] not in red_checkers.values():
                        movement_button_1_capture.place(x=checker_x - 100, y=checker_y - 100, anchor=CENTER)
                        movement_button_1_capture.configure(command=lambda: capture_movement_1(
                            key2, specific_checker, 'black', checker_x - 100, checker_y - 100))
                        break
```

I then create the buttons that the capture and movement functions use and finish with root.mainloop():

```
movement_button_1 = Button(root, image=green_circle, border="0")
movement_button_2 = Button(root, image=green_circle, border="0")
movement_button_1_capture = Button(root, image=green_circle, border="0")
movement_button_2_capture = Button(root, image=green_circle, border="0")

root.mainloop()
```

This is the entire code and it is also there in the Zip file attached at the end of this question. The Zip file also contains the relevant images and the main.py file so that you can run the program on your computer directly from that file.

I think the bug emerges in the 'capture_movement_1' and 'capture_movement_2' functions. After a capture is made. I run a loop to reassign the 'basic_movement' command to each checker. Perhaps this command assigns old values for some reason or the entire function uses an outdated version of the dictionary. This is the only explanation I can find since this bug occurs only after captures. The code snipet I am talking about is below:

```
            for k in list_of_keys_red:
                dict_of_red_checkers[k + 1].configure(command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=red_checkers[
                    k + 1][0], checker_y=red_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                    "red", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))

            for k in list_of_keys_black:
                dict_of_black_checkers[k + 1].configure(
                    command=lambda specific_checker=k + 1, checker_x=black_checkers[
                        k + 1][0], checker_y=black_checkers[k + 1][1]: basic_movement(
                        "black", specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y))
```

The Zip file is attached below as I have mention earlier:
[Zip File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/161aonyKFwCCDXZvCbNDv0p7vWFuUpZ3e/view?usp=sharing)

I have now spent several hours Debugging with no improvements whatsoever so I have nothing to show for those attempts. I felt it necessery to explain the code for anyone looking at this project for the first time (thus the post is so long)

Comment: This is way too much code, please look at how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Rory I have explained how to create a minimal reproducible example in the very beginning. The rest of the post simply explains the code and gives background information to attempt fixing the bug. You can refer to the Zip file if you want the code in one place and not broken into code blocks.

Comment: This really isn't a proper question for stackoverflow. You're not so much asking a programming question as you are asking us to debug your code for you. You should attempt to create a new [mcve] that reproduces your problem. That process will help you to understand the root of the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Please red the question properly, I am not asking for you to debug the code and I have given a reproducible example within the first 10 lines of the question. The reason it is so long and looks like I am asking you to debug is that I have spent the majority of the question explaining how the code works. If I skipped that and jumped straight to the specific part where the bug occurs (which I did at the end) you wouldn't understand at all what is going on. The question is actually like 20 lines. The rest of the Post just explains exactly how the code works.

Comment: Instead of explaining how the code works, you should focus on creating a _minimal_ example that reproduces the problem. We shouldn't have to download code from another site, or painstakingly copy and paste a dozen blocks of code. Nobody is going to want to do that.

Comment: @BryanOakley As I mentioned before, a demonstration to recreate the code in the form of a video and images is available within the first 10 lines of the question. You don't have to copy and past the several blocks of code because I have attached a ZIP file at the end, though if you want I can edit the post to add the entire code as a block. Also the answer doesn't have to debug the entire code, it is likely a problem with the block of code I mentioned at the end. For your answer you can just tell me how to alter that to get the code working. 

I have spent over 200 hours on this code now :(

Comment: When you print out the values of `checker_x` and `checker_y` arguments of `basic_movement()` and the values of the corresponding dictionary (`red_checkers` or `black_checkers`), they do not match for the issue red button.  Why don't you use the corresponding checkers instead of the passed `checker_x` and `checker_y`?

Comment: @acw1668 I'm happy you attempted to answer my question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What I suggest is to add `checker_x, checker_y = (red_checkers if color == "red" else black_checkers)[specific_checker]` at the beginning of `base_movement()` to use the corresponding checker's location instead of passed arguments `checker_x` and `checker_y`.

Comment: @acw1668 please post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the values of the arguments `checker_x` and `checker_y` of `basic_movement()` somehow are not the same as the location of the corresponding *checkers* (`red_checkers` or `black_checkers`).

Actually the location of the corresponding *checkers* can be used instead of the passed arguments:

```py
def basic_movement(color, specific_checker, checker_x, checker_y):
    # override the checker_x and checker_y by the location of the corresponding checkers
    checker_x, checker_y = (red_checkers if color == "red" else black_checkers)[specific_checker]
    ...
```